# laravel 5 Add unique constrain for a field that has the same foreign key id

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have an employee table which have name and id, and i have an employee_off_date table which have employee_id and date.  I want to add a unique constrain for the date for employee id. For example, if employee_id 1 have date of 3/30/2016 another employee_id 1 can't have the same date of 3/30/2016 , but employee_id 2 can have date of 3/30/2016.  Is there anyway i can do this in laravel 5 or mysql?  or should i manually write this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up the table to have a unique composite key.  If you want to do this via a migration, you could do something like the following:

```
Schema::table('employee_off_date', function($table) {
    $table->unique(['employee_id', 'date']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique constraint on table which will restrict insertion of duplicate combination of id and date, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE employee_off ADD CONSTRAINT ux_employee_off 
UNIQUE (employee_id, date)
```